# to select latest date and last but-one date from date column in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have to select latest date and last but-one date from date column and group by `ID` column.

So that I can get latest date and last but-one date for particular ID.

Suppose,

```
-----------------------------
ID          Date
-----------------------------
AA      5/5/2012
AA      6/5/2012
BB      19/5/2012
BB      20/5/2012
BB      18/5/2012
BB      17/5/2012
CC      8/5/2012
CC      19/5/2012
CC      20/5/2012
```

Required output

```
-----------------------------
ID          Date
-----------------------------
AA      6/5/2012
AA      5/5/2012
BB      20/5/2012
BB      19/5/2012
CC      20/5/2012
CC      19/5/2012
```

Comment: Mismatch: title says 2005. Tags say 2008 R2...

Comment: Also: SQL Server **2005** (as mentioned in title) doesn't have a `DATE` datatype.... (only `DATETIME`)

Answer (score 2):

Simple use of [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=sql.90%29.aspx):

```
;WITH OrderedRows as (
    SELECT ID,Date,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date desc) rn
    from Table
)
select * from OrderedRows where rn <=2
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: Resorting to INSERT with UNION ALL for sql-server-2005. sql-server-2008 + would use multi-values list.

```
CREATE TABLE #dates(
    id CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    dt DATE NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO #dates(
    id,
    dt
)
SELECT
    'AA','2012-05-05'
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'AA','2012-05-06'
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'BB','2012-05-19'
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'BB','2012-05-20'
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'BB','2012-05-18'
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'BB','2012-05-17'
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'CC','2012-05-08'
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'CC','2012-05-19'
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'CC','2012-05-20';

SELECT
    id,
    dt,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt DESC) AS seq_id
INTO
    #dates_seq
FROM
    #dates;

SELECT
    id,
    dt
FROM 
    #dates_seq
WHERE
    seq_id<=2
ORDER BY
    id,
    dt DESC;

DROP TABLE #dates_seq;
DROP TABLE #dates;
```

Answer (score 0):

One more option

```
SELECT *
FROM Table5 t
WHERE t.Date IN(
                SELECT TOP 2 t2.Date
                FROM Table5 t2
                WHERE t.ID = t2.ID
                ORDER BY t2.Date DESC
                )
```

Answer (score 0):

please check [MSDN solution](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SQLExamples/Wiki/View.aspx?title=SelectTopNByGroup) for SQL Server 2005 / SQL Server 2008.